# Unknown table multidelete in joined delete mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have couple tables linked like this:

1. roads (id, name)
2. houses (id,rid,name,housenumber) linked to roads by a column: "rid".
3. loans (id,rid) linked to roads by a column: "rid".
4. loan-entries (id,lid,housenumber) linked to loans by column: "lid", and by housenumber.

When user want to delete a house, I have to remove loan entries with the specific house number.

So from house id i get road id, after that i can get loans related to that road, and delete all loan-entries with lid, and housenumber.

I wrote queries with sub selects for this, but i guess with joins it could be much faster.
I stucked here. I'm not even sure i do what i want, and i get a mysql error message:

> "Unknown table 'le' in MULTI DELETE".

I tried some variations but can't figure it out.

My query:

```
DELETE le 
FROM `roads` AS r 
LEFT JOIN `loans` AS l ON l.rid = r.id 
LEFT JOIN `loan-entries` AS le ON le.lid = l.id 
LEFT JOIN `houses` AS h ON h.rid = r.id 
WHERE h.id = '" . $_POST['id'] . "' 
  AND le.housenumber = h.housenumber
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)? What you've got looks like a `SELECT`, not a `DELETE FROM [...]`.

Comment: Dave, that is not correct. Have a look at the manual.

Comment: @Richard OK fair enough, I have never seen that syntax before.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: ofc i checked delete syntax, actually i found the idea of using join at deletion in the mysql delete syntax page.

"DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;"

Comment: That's deleting a table, not a column. Look at the syntax again.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is a little late to answer this, but the issue is that you can only delete the leftmost table.
For this you need to reorganize your join a little. As you are deleting from 'le' table using left joins, you really only need those values from 'r' and 'l' tables which are joined via inner join, so start from 'le' table then inner join 'r' and 'l' and then continue to 'h'.